# How have I visited on more days than I've been registered?

Tags: support, profile-page, visited-days

I've noticed on my Area51 profile page that my visited days are greater that my member days, how is this possible?

[image: SteB Visited Days]

Comment: Nothing to worry about, just a time dilation effect. If it bothers you, perhaps you should consider slowing down.

Comment: Its only 9:39AM UTC at time of writing... You've been a member for 46.X days but you are already here today so visited for 47 days...

Comment: Well, the "visited" also count the current day as whole day even if it just started. Let's take simple example of a new user who registered yesterday. The "member for" will still show one day but the visited will show two days since the current day that isn't yet over is also counted.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - could it also count the day before I registered from a cookie? Either way your comment makes sense, I'll upvote,... just need an answer to accept.

Comment: I started it as answer then realized I might be just wrong so prefer to somehow prove it first. Anyway, click on the "47 days, 44 consecutive" text and small calendar will pop. Can you see what is the first green day that appears there? Is it really day before you actually registered?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I get the pop-up calendar on SO & MSO, but not Area51.

Comment: @SteB OK, but can you see what is the first green day that appears there? Is it really day before you actually registered?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The 1st green day on SO (& other sites) looks right, but I can't remember the date I registered (& Area51 doesn't have a pop-up calendar), so it's probably nothing to do with any cookie, your explanation makes more sense.

Comment: @Lix - I normally check my most/all sites that I'm a member of early in the day, Area51 is the only one that exhibits this behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because you were registered for 46 **whole days** however, you have visited on that **part** day as well. Therefore you have visited 47 days, however the member for is only incremented at 6 PM Central Time. The member for 46 days is rounded down. 
Say you have 46.9 days (5PM Central Time), it is still rounded down to 46.

Comment: This is a well documented problem in computer science: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error