# Area 51 user profile shows self-conflicting visit statistics

Tags: bug, area-51

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Consecutive days problem #97?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97)
>   [How have I visited on more days than I’ve been registered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155743/how-have-i-visited-on-more-days-than-ive-been-registered)

In my Area 51 user profile (https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/...) I see the following:

[image]

How is it possible to become a member without visiting the page?

Comment: It shows 2013-01-14 20:18:25. So it is about 23 hours.

Comment: No, 24 actually, all times are UTC times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do more than log in to count as a 'visit'. Merely joining doesn't count as activity for that counter.

Quoting from [Consecutive days problem #97?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97):

> We see a login on 10-2 but no access to internal pages (login pages, along with a number of other homepage style pages, don't count as "access").

So, yesterday you logged in, but didn't do enough to increase the visits counter.

Comment: @SzilágyiDonát: There is nothing buggy about it; it's `status-bydesign` in fact.